# cannot find cgroup V2 controllor

Tags: cgroups

guys
I've mounted cgroup V2 manually but I found there are none controllor in the root hierarchy.

```
[root@node5 /]# mount -t cgroup2 none /cgroup2/
[root@node5 /]# cd cgroup2/
[root@node5 cgroup2]# ls
cgroup.controllers  cgroup.max.descendants  cgroup.stat             cgroup.threads
cgroup.max.depth    cgroup.procs            cgroup.subtree_control
[root@node5 cgroup2]# cat cgroup.controllers 
[root@node5 cgroup2]# uname -r
5.0.0-rc6+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. It's really due to the fact that, very likely, you have both the older cgroups v1 as well as the newer cgroups v2 present, IOW, they're mixed. Now no controllers show up in v2.

What you can do is disable v1 and retry. To disable cgroups v1, reboot the box passing this kernel command-line parameter via your bootloader (GRUB, if on an x86):

```
cgroup_no_v1=all
```

After booting with this, pl mount and check, it should show up (provided of course it's configured in the kernel).